# What word processor do you use for technical papers?

Tags: word-processor

I've been looking for some time for a word processor to use for writing technical papers and I haven't really found one.  What would really be nice to have is an editor that can handle mathematical expressions, code, and pseudo-code fairly well.  I have yet to find one that works very well.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer's long, so I want to say up front:  I think you want OpenOffice Writer (I use v2.4, haven't tried 3.0 yet).

I've used Word with equation editor and LaTeX heavily in the past and OpenOffice Writer
more recently.  I used the former two while writing my thesis.

LaTeX may still have advantages in quality of the output and in the ability to use text-based version control, but they're sharply diminished by OO Writer at this point.

Microsoft with equation editor, even the most recent versions, seems very weak still.

What I like about OpenOffice is that you can use the equation formatting mechanisms
in a mode where the window is split between the document you're writing and another
area where you can type very LaTeX-like formatting instructions.  One of the *big*
strengths of LaTeX is that you get to type up something like $x \in S$ for "x is an element of S".  OO Writer lets you do this *and* see the result.

Back when I wrote my thesis, LaTeX was preferable to Word with Eqn. Editor because of the length of my document (over 200 pages), the quality of the results, and the ease of specifying equations.  LaTeX does have a disadvantage in simplicity of use that is made more acute by OO Writer.

That said, I'm sure I'd use OO Writer for conference to journal length articles (~8-15 pages v. ~15-40 pages) and also for shorter work.  For thesis-length work, I'm not sure which I'd end up using:  Word never worked so well for me on longer matter; I suspect OO Writer is better behaved but I don't have enough experience of it to make a firm judgement.

Comment: I havn't used LaTeX, but I find MS Office2007 equation tool much better then OO.org's. I tried to like it, but I just couldn't

Comment: OO's equation editor is way better than the one i've been using w/ MS Word; I don't have the latest Word version, but OO is WYSIWYM rather than WYSIWYG. More like TeX.

Comment: In general, I've found Word's output to be of low quality and haven't found it easy to make adjustments to font and point sizes.  I also find the entry method more laborious.

Comment: Word 2007's formula editor allows for very much LaTeX-style text input. While the previous versions included a dumbed-down version of MathType and used OLE for math, the current one actually *has* math typesetting capabilities and I find them much more pleasant to use than LaTeX or OOo Writer.

Answer (score 28):

I personally believe in LaTeX.
Benefits:

- You can focus on content over form.
- Use logical rather than semantic formatting (e.g., \methodname vs. just italic).
- Easier to assemble large documents from multiple files.
- Use text-based version control (CVS/SVN/etc.)
- Widely used
- Much more stable even on super-weak machines
- Programmable. For example, I use macros to hide stuff, highlight stuff, obfuscate names by using a macro name with the real name but an obfuscated replacements.
- See all the tips and tricks available on SO.
- Output looks the same no matter which platform you compile on. Never had that luck with word, each version and each machine produces something slightly different.

Comment: That's all true... But I've found that, when I'm hacking TeX, I spend more of my time in documentation or typing formatting than I do actually writing the stuff I want.  But that's just me.

Comment: LaTeX is not for everyone...
I find it to be a perfect fit to how I think about my text. Though LaTeX does demand a dual-screen to work with effectively.
I never felt that the formatting takes too much of my time.

Comment: One of the most compelling reasons being your 4th - being able to use a good version control system was a life saver.  I was able to not only keep my thesis synchronized between work and home, but the backup aspect of version control was a great comfort.

Comment: Another useful item is the ease of adding bibliography entries.

Answer (score 5):

I like LyX (http://www.lyx.org/) -- it's a good tradeoff between "spending all your time writing your document" and "spending all your time writing markup".  The most recent versions are even useable!

Apart from that, Word 2008 is actually pretty darn good, provided you use the styles and other "advanced" features.

Answer (score 5):

I fully agree that L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X is a good choice. I've used for paper in univ, including my master thesis. For L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X I've been using [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/).

But nowadays there is interesting alternative which is [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/whatis) with [MathML extension](http://www.docbook.org/schemas/mathml.html).

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX with [TexMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html) got me through grad school.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "Word Processor". If you don't mind not having a WYSIWYG interface, I'd recommend LaTeX (http://www.latex-project.org/).

I wrote my final year Master's dissertation using it, which contained a lot of pseudocode, formulas, etc. Also outputs in a format fairly typical of technical papers.

Answer (score 2):

I use [FrameMaker](http://www.adobe.com/products/framemaker/).

Answer (score 1):

MS Word with [Mathtype](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/). It has a number of advantages over the default Equation editor, including, but not limited to:

- keyboard shortcuts
- writing equations in tex mode then converting them
- converting equations from "normal" to "linear" mode (the one you can use in your programs, you know a=b/c and such)
- templates
- no more latex. I can concentrate on the material, not the writing

Answer (score 0):

Word with MS Equation for the mathematical sections.

Answer (score 0):

I like [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/) and use [FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to create PDFs from it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) because it can be used in [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), converted to PDF and HTML, have little markup overhead, and looks nice in its plain form too.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Word is considered as the market standard word editor.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is for you to use [Authorea](https://authorea.com).

As a former postdoc (Astrophysics) and Ph.D. (Informatics) with 12+ years research experience (Harvard, CERN, UCLA), I have written technical papers for a long time. I have loved and hated LaTeX. For the past 2 years, I have worked with friends and colleagues at developing the next generation platform for writing technical/research documents collaboratively. It is called Authorea. From a technical standpoint Authorea is built on Git and takes LaTeX, Markdown, HTML (even JS, to include fancy d3.js in your papers). Bonus: you don't need to know LaTeX (or any other format) but you can easily add equations, tables, citations, and data to your papers. I hope you'll find it useful.